# How to get id of spinner, radiobutton, checkboxs in android

Tags: android, checkbox, radio-button, android-spinner

I have 3 list with spinner, radiobutton and checkboxes in respective list as shown below.

```
List<Spinner> ls= new  ArrayList<Spinner>();
List<RadioButton> ls= new  ArrayList<RadioButton>();
List<CheckBbox> ls= new  ArrayList<CheckBbox>();
```

Iam loading these list into a tableview, after loading when I click on any one of spinner or radiobutton or checkbox I want to know which one is clicked.I want ID to locate that cell and after that I want to add a edittext to that same cell. How can I get the ID of that cell when user is clicked?I am stuck at this point.

After loading the list code goes like this

**In button getting id using view.getId(), but how to in spinner?**

`cellRow` is cell id;

```
_spinner.setId(cellRow);
listSpinner.add(_spinner);

                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view1, int pos, long id) {

                                for (int d = 0; d < listSpinner.size(); d++){

                                    if (listSpinner.get(d).getId()==(view.getId)){
                                        spinnerString = "";
                                        spinnerString =listSpinner.get(d).getSelectedItem().toString();
                                        Log.i("SPINN", "Selected Spinner value=" + spinnerString );
                                        Log.i(" Cell ID", "Row id="+cellRow+" Coloumn id="+cellColumn+" spinner id="+listSpinner.get(d).getId());

                                        // then display edittext
                                        tvSpinnerHeading = new TextView(context);
                                        etSpinnerOtherValue = new EditText(context);
                                        tvSpinnerHeading.setText("Specify values:   ");;
                                }
                                        return;

                                }
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                                Log.i("Display", "onNothingSelected");

                            }
                        });
```

But am not getting the ID, Can anyone help me to find where am doing wrong?

Comment: where is your getId() function... it should the id's

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to assign an "id" to them using:

```
spinner.setTag(Object obj)
```

You can use virtually anything as a tag, but a String or Int works well...

Comment: I already set id using this: _spinner.setId(cellRow);, but how to get id if i click spinner. in button getting id using view.getId(), but how to in spinner?